# How efficiently use MySQL for Stock/TimeSeries related data?

Tags: mysql, time-series

I use Python and MySQL to ingest data via API and generate signals and order execution. Currently, things are functional yet coupled, that is, the single script is fetching data, storing it in MySQL, generating signals, and then executing orders. By tightly coupled does not mean all logic is in the same file, there are separate functions for different tasks. If somehow the script breaks everything will be halted. The way DB tables are generated is based on the instrument available on the fly after running a filter mechanism. The python code creates a different table of the same schema but with different table names based on the instrument name.

Now I am willing to separate the parts:

1. Data Ingestion (A Must)
2. Signal Generation
3. Order Execution
4. Reporting

First three I am mainly focusing. My concern is that if separate processes are running, acting on the same tables, will it generate any lock or something? How do I take care of it smoothly? or, is MySQL good enough for this or I move on to some other DB Like Postgres or others?
We are already using Digital Ocean Instance, MySQL is currently installed on the same instance.

Comment: There are locks in mysql and a lot of other databases cus people use the locks for certain scenarios, this question can lead to an opinion based question

Comment: Offcourse locks are normal but certain RDBMs are easy to scale...

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to ingest/query time-series at scale, a conventional RDBMS will fall short at one point or another. They are designed for a use case in which reads are more frequent than writes, and optimise for that.

There is a whole family of databases designed specifically for working with Time-Series data. These time-series databases can ingest data at high throughput while running queries on top, and they usually give you lifecycle capabilities so you can decide what to do when data keeps growing.

There are [many options available,](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking/time+series+dbms) both open source and proprietary. Out of those databases I would recommend you to try [QuestDB](https://questdb.io/) because of a few reasons:

- It is open source and Apache 2.0 licensed, so you can use it anywhere for anything
- It is a single binary (or docker container) to operate
- You query data using SQL, (with extensions for time series)
- You can insert data using SQL, but you will experience locks if using concurrent clients. However you can also ingest data using the ILP protocol which is designed for ingestion speed. There are [official clients in 7 languages](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/clients/overview) so you don't have to deal with the low-level details
- It is blazingly fast. I have seen over 2 million inserts per second on a single instance and some users report sustained workloads of over 100,000 events per second
- It is [well supported on Digital Ocean](https://questdb.io/docs/deployment/digitalocean/)
- There are a lot of public references (and many users who are not a reference) in the finance/trading/crypto industries